# Moving forward and backward in Street View API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, unity-game-engine, unityscript, google-street-view

I'm integrating the [Google Street View API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/) in Unity for a VR project and I would like to know if it's possible to find the next longitude and latitude if we move on the street.

If you are using Street View in Google maps, you can click on arrows to move forward or backward on the street.

When you click on the arrow, you are basically moved to a new longitude and latitude.

I wanted to know if it's possible to add a similar action using the Street View API.

Here is a part of the code I use to load the Street View API:

```
string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?"
            + "size=" + width + "x" + height
            + "&location=" + latitude + "," + longitude
            + "&heading=" + (heading + sideHeading) % 360.0 + "&pitch=" + (pitch + sidePitch) % 360.0  
            + "&fov=90.0&sensor=false";

        if (key != "")
            url += "&key=" + key;

        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
            Debug.Log("Panorama " + name + ": " + www.error);
        else
            print("Panorama " + name + " loaded url " + url);

        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
```

So that when you click on the UP arrow can could move on the Street View.

Comment: The [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Streetview Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) returns "links" to the adjacent panoramas.